# spectral sequences in number theory

Tags: nt.number-theory

What is your favorite examples of spectral sequences arising naturally in arithmetic geometry?
Please explain it in some detail

Comment: Out of curiosity: Why do you want to know this?

Comment: I'll let Wikipedia explain.  See the last reference listed on that page: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lyndon-Hochschild-Serre_spectral_sequence

Comment: -1: MO is meant for specific questions about research level mathematics.  This one is a fishing expedition: "tell me something interesting about subject X".  Moreover, you haven't identified yourself or provided any information about your background knowledge in spectral sequences and/or arithmetic geometry or told us why you are interested.  

Comment: While I agree with the spirit of the comment, in fairness, I've seen an incredible number of such "fishing expedition" questions recently and hardly anyone complains. I don't quite understand what makes this one that much different: is it a bias against "unknown" as a name?

Comment: @Victor, I suggest you ask on meta.

Comment: Sorry for asking such a question...Could I delete it ?

Comment: @unknown, that would be unfair to Ivan who has spent some of his time writing up an answer.  Why not just edit your question to add background per Mariano's question?

Comment: @Victor: this particular case is extreme in its lack of context (and yes, being anonymous does not help in providing context; if, say, Qiaochu Yuan had asked this question, then a would-be answerer would have a lot more to go on) but also is clearly ON topic as a MO question content-wise.  Therefore I did not vote to close but downvoted: I am hoping for an improvement.  

Comment: I'm neutral as to whether or not this question is taken down. If people find the comments/answers here useful, then perhaps leaving it up is ok.


Answer (score 9, accepted):

I posit the following example, in response to your ambiguous question:

The coniveau spectral sequence seems to play an important role in 'arithmetic geometry'. One instance is in class field theory for schemes:

From W. Raskind's nice survery article "Abelian class field theory of arithmetic schemes" [AMS, 1992, pgs. 100-101]:

Let $X$ be an arithmetic scheme, $n>0$ invertible on $X$. Then there is a coniveau spectral sequence (in the etale site):

$$E^{p,q}_1 = \bigoplus _{ x\in X^{p} } H^{q-p} (k(x), \;\mathbb{Z}/n  \; (j-p)) \Rightarrow H^{p+q} (X, \mathbb{Z}/n \;(j)) $$

Without going into more details, this sequence plays an important role in defining a reciprocity map from a class group of $X$ to abelian fundamental groups.

That's all I will say for now in hopes that the above provides for motivation to delve further into studying coniveau, etc.

Finally, one of the best articles I have seen on coniveau is by Colliot-Thélène, Hoobler, and Kahn, "The Bloch-Ogus-Gabber theorem" which can be found at:
http://www.math.jussieu.fr/~kahn/preprints/prep.html

It might be nice to have others' remarks/comments on coniveau, but I don't have any precise questions yet.

Comment: also, I second Mariano's question above.

Comment: "Khan" is Kahn and "Colliot-Thelene" is Colliot-Thélène.  For a different approach to "abelian class field theory of arithmetic schemes", see recent papers by Moritz Kerz.  A good beginning would be the Bourbaki exposé by Tamás Szamuely (Corps de classes des schémas arithmétiques, Séminaire Bourbaki, exposé 1006, mars 2009. Astérisque 332 (2010), 257--286) available on his webpage http://www.renyi.hu/~szamuely/

Comment: Thanks for the spelling corrections; I've incorporated them. I've also placed the authors' names in the order appearing in their paper